# Keep rows together while sorting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I need to sort a column of data in which some rows are subsets of 1 row. I'd like these to stay together as the association is entirely visual (I have not created additional fields to handle this and don't want to).

Is it possible in Excel to sort but keep certain groups together? I'm happy to do it manually as this is a series of little lists that I manually edit. But I do need to re-sort every time I add anything and manual sorting sucks.

Example:

```
Main item1
  Sub item1
  Sub item1
Main item2
  Sub item2
Main item3
Main item4
  Subitem4
```

Comment: This can be easily solved by Group & Sort command. Please Upload proper Screen shot.

Comment: Is Group & Sort one command? Where is it?

Comment: Ok, I have found the group command but it doesn't keep things together while sorting. It literally groups a set of rows regardless of contents and moves the contents out of the cells so that the contents is not kept together. The grouping remains and I can still minimise but now it has different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (I have not created additional fields to handle this and don't want
>   to).
>
> Is it possible in Excel to sort but keep certain groups together?

No, there is no way to keep them together while sorting without a helper column.